# How can I refresh the table view but disable the bounce?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to disable my `scrollview` bounce when scroll down.

[image]

When I disable bounce vertically I can't `refresh` my table.
Any suggestion how to disable bounce, but enable refresh table?

I'm refreshing this way:

```
self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
    getJson()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"disable bounce"*? What do you mean?

Comment: I think there are no way to do it.

Comment: how are you trying to refresh your table view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just did it this way:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0.0 {
        return
    }

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height), animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` method in the `UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
  extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
      func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
          if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
              scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0), animated: false)
          }
      }
    }
```

This allows the table view to pull to refresh down, but restricts pulling up. This removes the bounce in the upwards direction.

Side-effect: this will not let you go beyond the cells already on view, so you can't scroll down to cells not visible.